# How to insert a 2D Array into Database using c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, for-loop, nested-loops

I have a `two dimensional array with 3 columns and 2 rows`. I also have a `database table with 3 columns`. I want to insert the 2D array directly into the database.

Is there any way to that?

Any help is appreciated. I can supply more details if needed.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace _2DArrayIntoDatabaseTest
{

public partial class Form1 : Form
{

 string[,] LoginInfo = new string[2, 3]{{"1", "Admin", "123"},{"2", "Admin2", "456"}};
 string query;
 SqlCommand Sqlcmd;
 SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=MIRAZ-PC\SQLEXPRESS;
                      Initial Catalog=2DArrayIntoDatabaseTest;
                      Integrated Security=True");
 DataTable dbdataset;

 public Form1()
 {
  InitializeComponent();
 }

 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
  this.tTableAdapter.Fill(this._2DArrayIntoDatabaseTestDataSet.t);
 }

 int i = 0, j = 0;

 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

  try
  {

   for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
   {

    for (j = 0; j < 3;j++ )
     query = "INSERT INTO t(SerialNumber,UserName,Password) 
             values( '" + LoginInfo[i, 0] + "','" 
                        + LoginInfo[i, 1] + "','" 
                        + LoginInfo[i, 2] + "')";
   }

   Sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
   conn.Open();
   Sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   conn.Close();

  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
   MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
  }

  try
  {

   query = "SELECT * from t";
   Sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
   conn.Open();
   SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
   sda.SelectCommand = Sqlcmd;
   dbdataset = new DataTable();
   sda.Fill(dbdataset);
   BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();
   bSource.DataSource = dbdataset;
   dataGridView1.DataSource = bSource;
   sda.Update(dbdataset);
   //dataGridView1.Columns.Remove("rownum");

  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
   MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
  }
  finally
  {
   conn.Close();
  }
}
}
}
```

Now this piece of code compiles fine. But in Data Grid View I can only see 1 row instead of 2.

How to solve that?

**Note:** Here I am trying to use a nested loop to create a dynamic query to insert a row of data one at a time.

Comment: Please, show us the actual code that is not working?

Comment: There are as many ways to do this as there are programmers in the world. Make an attempt, ask for help with that attempt. Until then, I have to vote to close.

Comment: @CodeNotFound - just had to laugh about your username "CodeNotFound" while you are writing a comment about missing code. :D

Comment: I assumed that my attempt was a total failure. So I assumed that I should ask for specialist help. Then again I shared my failed attempt. I would like you to check my code @Joel Coehoorn.

Comment: Side Note: Your query variable is overwritten after each iteration

Comment: It is **NEVER** okay to use string concatenation to put data into an sql command.

Comment: Can you please elaborate the problem. Half my code uses string concatenation. What type of risk I am taking? @JoelCoehoorn

Comment: Your string concatenation is wide open to sql injection. It is the absolute worst possible way to get data into the database. But my friend bobby tables LOVES this type of thing. http://bobby-tables.com/ Learn how to use parameterized queries, then go back and fix ALL of your code.

Comment: Imagine you have a username with a value like `O'Brien`, or even just mistakenly enters that last name instead of the username into the username field. Think carefully how your code will respond to that. And that's just a naive example. Imagine you have a hacker who knows how to take advantage of this, including ways to get past the common work-arounds. Parameterized queries are the **only** safe way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `[i, 1]`, `[i, 2]`, and `[i, 3]` you need `[i, 0]`, `[i, 1]`, and `[i, 2]`. Also, `ExecuteNonQuery()` needs to happen *inside* the `for` loop.

While I'm here, I'll also show some better practice on including data in with the SQL query. The current code is crazy-vulnerable to sql injection.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string query = "INSERT INTO t(SerialNumber,UserName,Password) VALUES (@serial, @user, @pass);";
    var dbdataset = new DataTable();

    //ADO.Net does better if you create new objects, rather than try to re-use them through a class or application.
    // The "using" blocks will make sure things are closed and disposed properly, even if an exception is thrown
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=MIRAZ-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=2DArrayIntoDatabaseTest;Integrated Security=True"))
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
    {   
        //I had to guess at column types and lengths here.
        // You should use actual column types and lengths from the DB
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@serial", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@user", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20);  
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@pass", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20);
        conn.Open();

        for (i = 0; i < LoginInfo.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
        {
            cmd.Parameters["@serial"].Value = LoginInfo[i, 0];
            cmd.Parameters["@user"].Value = LoginInfo[i, 1];
            cmd.Parameters["@pass"].Value = LoginInfo[i, 2];

            try
            {
                //don't forget to do this INSIDE the loop
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }

        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM t";
        var sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        try
        {
            sda.Fill(dbdataset);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dbdataset;
}
```

Last of all... plain-text passwords like this are **NOT GOOD.**

---

Here's an example using a `List<UserLoginInfo>`. Note moving code to the new `DB` class here is not required for the List to work; it's just good practice to do that anyway.

```
public class UserLoginInfo
{
    public string SerialNumber {get;set;} //you might want an int here instead
    public string Username {get;set;}
    public string Password {get;set;}
}

public static class DB
{
    private static readonly string ConnectionString = @"Data Source=MIRAZ-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=2DArrayIntoDatabaseTest;Integrated Security=True";

    public static void SaveUserData(IEnumerable<UserLoginInfo> users)
    {
        string query = "INSERT INTO t(SerialNumber,UserName,Password) VALUES (@serial, @user, @pass);";

        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
        {   
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@serial", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@user", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20);  
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@pass", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20);
            conn.Open();

            foreach(var user in users)
            {
                cmd.Parameters["@serial"].Value = user.SerialNumber;
                cmd.Parameters["@user"].Value = user.UserName;
                cmd.Parameters["@pass"].Value = user.Password;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }

    public static DataTable GetLoginData()
    {
        var result = new DataTable();
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM t", conn))
        using (var sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            sda.Fill(result);
        }
        return result;
    }
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private List<UserLoginInfo> LoginInfo = new List<UserLoginInfo> {
        new UserLoginInfo() {SerialNumber = "1", Username = "Admin", Password = "123"}, 
        new UserLoginInfo() {SerialNumber = "2", UserName = "Admin2", Password = "456"}
    };

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try 
        {
            DB.SaveUserData(LoginInfo);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = DB.GetLoginData();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: I may add that "It is a 0-based index" :)

Comment: Tried. The code compiled at least but giving weird value. The Data Grid View is not showing the first row.  @Joel Coehoorn

Comment: @KhandkarAsifHossain Side Note: Your query  variable is overwritten after each iteration

Comment: @KhandkarAsifHossain then it is another issue that should be on its own question :) The actual issue occured wih an exception thrown is solved hre.

Comment: How can I prevent that. @Karthik Ganesan

Comment: put  your database related code inside the for loop or concatenate your query variable "using query += Insert into ...."

Comment: I have already done that.`for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                //for (j = 0; j < 3;j++ )
                    query = "INSERT INTO t(SerialNumber,UserName,Password) values( '" + LoginInfo[i, 1] + "','" + LoginInfo[i, 2] + "','" + LoginInfo[i, 3] + "')";
            }`

Comment: First problem. Do I have to create `cmd.add` for all the rows individually? Actually the piece of code I shared here is a minimal version of my actual work. In my actual project the row numbers are crazy high around(360 rows). Is there any work around? @JoelCoehoorn

Comment: @KhandkarAsifHossain Look more closely at the code. There's a `cmd.Parameters.Add()` **once** for each parameter, and **one** `cmd.Parameters["@name"].Value = ` for each parameter inside the loop. Adding more rows won't increase the amount of code here.

Comment: ... and really what you should have here is a `User` object with `Username`, `SerialNumber`, and `Password` fields, and then use a `List<User>` rather than a 2D array.

Comment: Got it. i just needed `Sqlcmd.ExcuteNonQuery` line into the loop. And for using `List` actually I really can't use that because in my actual array there will be some blank spaces. `List` doesn't give me the flexibility I need to compare and insert. Thanks @JoelCoehoorn

Comment: Sure it does. You can check for blanks in a list just like you can in an array. Easier, even.

Comment: And **PLEASE** look at how I changed the code. The code in the question is just _begging_ to get hacked. It is **NEVER** okay to use string concatenation to put data into an sql command.

Comment: `LoginInfo.GetUpperBound(0)` is getting 2 instead of 3. How to solve that. @JoelCoehoorn

Comment: Via `<=` instead of just `<`. But, again, a `List<User>` will be **much** better in the long run.

Comment: Can you please edit your answer using `List`. It would be a great help. @JoelCoehoorn

Comment: @KhandkarAsifHossain List example provided.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn (flying by from review queue and just happened to see this) Wow. This might be meaningless to you, but I'd like to commend you for the patience and kindness you show. Being able to both answer the question *and* explain about sql injection in one post is truly amazing. Just nice to see users like you here and there. :D

Answer (score 0):

Yes that can be done very easily. I have done this in vb.net as under.. I have taken array arr with 4 columns and two rows..

```
            Dim Arr()() = {({1, "Document Title", "TITLE", "C"}),
                          ({2, "Company Header1", "HEADER1", "C"})}
```

Now for inserting this into database you can simply run insert query for inserting data in your own way... for e.g.

```
    for each item in arr.items
         exexuteNonQuery("INSERT INTO Supplier (SupplierID, Name, abc,xyz) VALUES (@SID, @Name, @abc, @xyz)")
    next
```

Comment: Great answer because it provides the best practice about parametizing the query. This should be the accepted answer. Anyway the OP is using C# so you should a least convert it :)